# same fd in multiple epoll instances for seperate writing and reading threads

Tags: events, file-descriptors

can we use the same fd in multiple epollfds? I mean one epoll instance for catching EPOLLIN, one epoll instance for catching EPOLLOUT.

for example:

```
int fd = ... // the file descriptor
int epoll_reader = epoll_create1(0); // first epoll instance for reading
int epoll_writer = epoll_create1(0); // second epoll instance for writing
```

for reading I need these flags: `EPOLLIN | EPOLLET`

but for writing I don't want it to be edge-triggered, I want it to be level-triggered and pass only `EPOLLOUT`

registering for reader:

```
struct epoll_event ev;
ev.data.fd = fd;
ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
epoll_ctl(epoll_reader, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev);
```

registering for writer:

```
struct epoll_event ev;
ev.data.fd = fd;
ev.events = EPOLLOUT;
epoll_ctl(epoll_writer, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev);
```

the reason for doing this is to catch EPOLLIN as edge-trigger and catch EPOLLOUT as level-trigger.

as my code base got too large I cannot modify it and test it, I must make sure to do any changes on the code.